# GAPI Failed to authenticate user

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

```
 <?php 
   require('gapi.class.php');
   $ga = new gapi(_GAE_,_GAP_);
   $dimensions = array('source');
   $metrics = array('visits');
   $ga->requestReportData(_GAA_, $dimensions, $metrics,'-visits');
   $gaResults = $ga->getResults();
   $i=1;

   foreach($gaResults as $result)
    {
     printf("%-4d %-40s %5d\n",
       $i++,
       $result->getSource(),
       $result->getVisits());
    }
   echo "\n-----------------------------------------\n";
   echo "Total Results : {$ga->getTotalResults()}";    
 ?>
```

This code is from a GAPI tutorial, and I keep getting these errors or something on failed login, yet all my information is correct.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error: "GDatainsufficientPermissionsUser does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."' in public_html/admin/gapi.class.php:218 Stack trace: #0 


public_html/php/templates/pages/ga_advanced.php(11): gapi->requestReportData('52537078', Array, Array, '-visits') #1 

public_html/php/php_includes/easyCMSv2.php(43): include('/home/a3822536/...') #2

public_html/php/templates/pages/general_google_analytics.php(6): CMS->template('../php/template...') #3 

public_html/admin/gapi.class.php on line 218
```

Does anyone have any experience with this that could possibly explain what is wrong? I used the Account ID with out the `UA` and `-(n)` as well as it with it. EX: `UA-1238124hf-y` but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some digging I found the fix for this, you actually have to edit the GAPI.class php code. [You can read more here](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=79#c10)

Change line `32` to

```
   const account_data_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles';
```

Change lines `267` and `268` to

```
   $account_root_parameters['generator'] = strval($xml->generator);
   $account_root_parameters['generatorVersion'] = strval($xml->generator->attributes());
```

Change line `270` to

```
  $open_search_results = $xml->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/');
```

Change lines `322` and `323` to

```
 $report_root_parameters['generator'] = strval($xml->generator);
 $report_root_parameters['generatorVersion'] = strval($xml->generator->attributes());
```

Change line `325` to

```
 $open_search_results = $xml->children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/');
```

Hope that helps any other users looking and not finding a clear cut documentation.

Comment: I tried this, but its not working in function protected function authenticateUser($email, $password)
$post_variables = array(
   'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
   'Email' => $email,
   'Passwd' => $password,
   'setDeveloperKey'=>'abcdogjdsighsklghksdkgj',
   'source' => gapi::interface_name,
   'service' => 'analytics'
  );

Comment: Where is the protected function? In a class? for me `_GAE_` , `_GAA_` , and `_GAP_` all equaled to Google Analytics Email, Google Analytics ID, and Google Analytics Password. They are just defined consts.

Answer (score 2):

you are using the `ACCOUNT id` instead of the `PROFILE id` in your request.

the Profile id can be found when you login to GA click on the link to look at the stats of a specific profile (website) and in the URL you will see something like this:

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?#report/visitors-overview/axxxxxwxxxxxxxpXXXXXX/
```

the numbers after the "p" at the end of the URL is the Profile id

Answer (score 0):

What worked in my case was I needed to use the php code in

1. [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=79#c10)
2. And go to the [security settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) of your google account and enable **less secure**

Make sure you re-enable it back when you are done.

Comment: Actually when I tried #2, I don't think we need to do the #1 in here anymore. older PHP code still worked